# Use VueJS Variable inside html2-pdf

Tags: vue.js, html2pdf

i have use html2-pdf in VueJS project in terms of generate pdf file from HTML.
My problem is, is there way to use VueJS variable like `{{ variableName }}` inside tag `<section slot="pdf-content">` ?
Because i have tried but it not print out the value of the variableName. Is there any way to use variable inside the tag of `html2-pdf`?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried to use the 'v-bind:' or simply ':' before the parameter ? On vuejs if you want to pass a variable to a tag parameter, you simply need to do so : <section slot="pdf-content" :id="variableName"> (notice  the ':' in front of id). Try it out and tell us, it might not work with html2-pdf tho

Comment: Hi @LucasRoland,

Thank you before, but i've tried it still not get the value from that variable.
I try like this :
<section slot="pdf-content"  :id="payReqNo">
Inside this section i can not access the variable even i add the binding here.

Comment: Is is possible to add more code to your original post? In order to see what's going on with html2-pdf exactly